# get xy coordinates on html5 drop event

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

with html5 drag and drop, how do i get the x and y position of where the item was dropped on the drop event? i need to dynamically create and display an image and a popup at that point...not using the canvas

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard [clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientX) and [clientY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientY) properties:

```
function onDrop(ev) {
    window.alert( ev.clientX + ',' + ev.clientY);
    ev.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```